# how to parse this to get title in php

Tags: php, html, parsing

I want to parse HTML code present in $raw to get the title and save it mysql. I have tried to do it with php dom and Ganon HTML parser but when I run it, shows me an error 500. it would be great if you solve this problem with Ganon.

```
function store($raw)
{
    include_once('ganon.php');
    $html = file_get_dom($raw);
    echo $html('title', 0)->parent->getPlainText();
}
store ('<html> all html code </html>');
```

Comment: missing semicolon on your final statement calling store.

Comment: @Ultimater already done, i missed it here not in my actual code...so this is not the real problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code.

Firstly you use `file_get_dom()` which is expecting to be passed in a file name, so use`str_get_dom()` instead.

Secondly, the example HTML doesn't contain a title, so this won't work.

Then when you find the title, you go to the parent element and output from there.  You just need to use that nodes content.

```
include_once('ganon.php');

function store($raw)
{
    $html = str_get_dom($raw);
    echo $html('title', 0)->getPlainText();
}
store ('<html><title>Title</title> all html code </html>');
```

outputs...

```
Title of page
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49720655/how-to-check-if-a-tag-with-specific-title-attribute-is-present-in-html-by-ganon?noredirect=1#comment86454586_49720655 help in this one too