# how to check if a tag with specific title attribute is present in html by ganon in php

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, ganon

This is my code where raw contains an HTML string that has many "a href" tag with different title attributes, and I want to check if the string has a hyperlink tag with title "x". How can I do that by using Ganon HTML dom parser in PHP.

```
function store($raw, $link)
{
    $html = str_get_dom($raw);
    if ($html has a href tag with title = "x")
    {
        $anchor = $html('a[title = x]')->getPlainText();
        foreach($anchor as $abc)
        {
            echo $abc->title."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never heard of `Ganon`, you can't just use the native domdocument parser?

Comment: i had tried native one, but i didn't find a way to grab a tag by its title in native, so i switched to ganon a long time ago. i had already used ganon everywhere... and  i dont want to change it again. but you can suggest me an answer atleast... @chris85...

Comment: With Ganon I can't. With domdocument you can just pull the `a` elements, then look at the `title` attribute.

Comment: Can you give some sample html and how you would call `store()`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following, not sure exactly what you want to do, but this basically looks for the `<a>` with the title attribute which is the one you pass in (`$link`)  it then outputs the href attribute of this tag.  It would be easy to reverse it, but the main thing is the logic of how to find something by the attributes value and then display other parts of the element.

```
function store($raw, $link)
{
    $html = str_get_dom($raw);
    $anchor = $html('a[title = "'.$link.'"]');
    foreach($anchor as $abc)
    {
        echo $abc->href."<br>";
    }
}

$html = <<< HTML
<html><a href='abc' title='firsttitle'>linkxrefabc</a>
<a href='xref' title='title2'>linkxref</a></html>
HTML;

store($html, 'firsttitle');   // outputs abc<br>

store($html, 'title2');  // outputs xref<br>
```